# Problem starting DJI simulation [dji-sdk]

Tags: android, android-studio, dji-sdk

I'm trying to implement the sample code of [dji developer](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/quick-start/index.html#android-sample-app) for android but i can't start the app, i add my com.dji.sdk.API_KEY and when i launch the app i get this errors:

```
2020-04-03 19:44:10.734 5567-5607/com.dji.sdk.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.dji.sdk.sample, PID: 5567
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getUsbAccessoryAttachedString() (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getUsbAccessoryAttachedString and Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getUsbAccessoryAttachedString__)
    at dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getUsbAccessoryAttachedString(Native Method)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source:32)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.dji.sdk.sample.internal.controller.MainActivity$5.run(:241)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

If you need code of any thing i can post it too. Thanks.

EDIT:
I can do it with an hardware Samsung, not in virtual device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using an emulator, but the MSDK doesn't support it. 
It only works with a real device.